# C-x C-c not working in Emacs 23.1

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I am using Emacs 23.1 with Cygwin but when I try to exit by pressing C-x C-c it says C-x C-g is undefined and I am not able to exit.

Answer (score 25):

This problem can be fixed by inserting the following line in file `Cygwin.bat` 
before the line with `bash --login -i`:

```
set CYGWIN=tty notitle glob
```

File `Cygwin.bat` is in the root of the Cygwin installation and 
is also the file that there is a shortcut to in menu Start/Programs/Cygwin. 
The shortcut may be named `Cygwin Bash Shell`.

---

I have tested it and my version of the `Cygwin.bat` file now contains:

```
@echo off

e:
chdir e:\cygwin171\bin

set CYGWIN=tty notitle glob

bash --login -i
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me! Should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: @31eee384: you are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a Cygwin issue, interpreting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> as Interrupt and Emacs somehow translating that to *its* interrupt character, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>.

As a workaround, you can always exit Emacs by doing <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`save-buffers-kill-terminal` <kbd>⏎</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just solved it by adding a Windows environment variable called CYGWIN with the value "tty".