# How do I exit from Emacs to Cygwin?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I start Cygwin and type emacs and there I am in Emacs. The directions say: to exit type C-x C-c where C is the control key -- I am assuming that is the left control key.

So I hold down the left control key and type x. I get a C-x in the lower bottom of the window. I then try C-c which is holding down the left control key and hitting the c key. Nothing. Just a ding.

In fact I cannot exit from Emacs at all. Is there a way of exiting from Emacs which works?

Comment: Since this is not programming related, it should really be posted on superuser, but your problem can be solved by following this page: http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki?CygwinizedEmacsHOWTO

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/93771/c-x-c-c-not-working-in-emacs-23-1

Answer (score 7):

Try `M-x save-buffers-kill-emacs`, where `M-x` is probably `Alt-x` under Cygwin.

This command is the default binding for `C-x C-c`.

To save typing, try binding this command to a different key combination (ie. one that works under Cygwin). Or better yet, download a native Windows version of GNU Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to weirdness in Ctrl+C handling in Cygwin's default console. Emacs works much better in any of Cygwin's other terminals: mintty, rxvt, xterm.

Comment: Yes, please use mintty (or one of the others, but I think mintty looks better) instead of standard console, it is so much better.

Comment: Agreed, Cygwin's default terminal is pretty wretched.